# Incorrect Android Lint warning on Unused Resources

Tags: java, android, eclipse, lint

After I run Lint in Eclipse, it shows a list of unused resources, mainly drawable. 
Some of them are incorrect. It is saying that some of the resource are unused, but in fact, it is actually being used in array.xml.

E.g. 
The resource R.drawable.test appears to be unused

In array.xml,

```
<string-array name="icon">
        <item>test</item>
</string-array>
```

Then in my activity, I use following code to retrieve the resource

```
String[] icon = getResources().getStringArray(icon);
iconRes = getResources().getIdentifier(icon[itemPos], "drawable", this.getPackageName());
```

I tried to run lint in terminal and it's giving the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lint often produces **false positives** on unused resources.

You can set them to `Information` or `Ignore` instead of `Warning` (Window/Preferences/Android/Lint Error Checking/Performance/UnusedResources).

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to make this preference project-related - not Android Studio related?

Comment: @Dmitry As far as I know, this is an IDE setting, therefore it's global.

Comment: It's possible using `lint.xml`.

Comment: @Dmitry Great find!

Comment: "often"? It just keeps marking all my resources as unused no matter how many times I execute it